# Is it possible to get a list of processes that's doing actions on an application? (eg, bot on a game client controlling it)

Tags: c++, windows, dll, process

Like title,
Is it possible in some way to get processes that are hooked to your application?
Either directly, or via DLLs?

My application is written in C++ and it can obtain processes, windows, and DLLs just fine.
But I noticed that some "bots" can connect to it, without leaving an obvious DLL-trace which makes me forced to find other solutions on how to track bots.

You don't have to know anything about bots or so.. any answers to my primary question are very appreciated no matter your experience.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Depends on how they interact with your application. It might be a system socket, shared memory, filesystem, etc.

Comment: what if the "bot" just stop you from check?